# C# - Array of String to Comma Separated in Item Templete

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, eval, itemtemplate

I want to change string to comma in Eval function inside Repeater -> item templete
When i use it

```
Eval("RoleName").ToString().Replace(" ", ", ")
```

it only shows comma on first string word not all of them

```
Memeber, Admin SupuerAdmin User
```

But i want

```
Member, Admin, SuperAdmin, User
```

Comment: try this :Eval("RoleName").Replace(" ", ", ").ToString()

Answer (score 2):

use aggregate

```
var a = "Memeber Admin SupuerAdmin User";
var z = a.Split(' ').Aggregate((x, y) => x + ", " + y);
System.Console.WriteLine(z);
```

Comment: Eval("RoleName").ToString().Split(' ').Aggregate((x, y) => x + ", " + y); shows red line that expression expected..

Comment: do you have the proper includes?
using System.Linq;

Comment: Yes i have.... <%@ Import Namespace="System.Linq" %>

Comment: I dont know what other problems you may have, this answer your question.

Comment: @RaheelAhmed if this solution doesn't work for you then `Eval("RoleName")` isn't returning what you think it does.  This works based on what you provided.  I would set a temporary variable equal to `Eval("RoleName")` and see what exactly is there.

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) to transform an array of strings into a single delimited string.

String.Join(", ", Eval("RoleName"));

I'm not sure on the result type of Eval("RoleName"), but if it is a string[], it will work.

Comment: Yes it is string[], but String.Join(", ", Eval("RoleName")); not work